# How to get rid of grayed-out scrollbar when there is no overflow?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm want to add a vertical scrollbar to a section of my webpage if its content grows too big but a grayed-out scrollbar shows up even when the content is small enough to fit. What do I need to change to make the scrollbar show only when its needed?

Example code:

```
<div id="aaa">
</div>

#aaa {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Result screenshot:

[image]

JSFiddle link with live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGwg3/

Comment: `overflow-y: auto;` will disappear the scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/jjfMp/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the property overflow-y: scroll to overflow-y: auto